# Should I get email when my question has an answer or comment added?

Tags: support, notifications, email

I recently asked a question, which has received both comments and an answer.  I was expecting to get an email indicating that there was a response, but have not seen one.  I also did not find a place in my profile to indicate if I wanted to receive such an email.

Should I have received such an email?  Is there a way to turn email notification on and off?

My email account is with gmail, in case it is known that their spam filters block email from this site.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get emails by default, unless you've specifically enabled that when you ask a question.

[image]

For comments & other notifications, you can click on email settings and enable the email notifications for your **unread** notifications.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe there is a delay (days) before the email notification is sent, and if you read your inbox before that *delay* is up, the notification is ***not*** sent. I looked in my emails and I haven't received such a notification for months. I looked at one such (old) notification and found the email was dated about 3 days after the event happened. I only checked one such notification, so it could be a *fluke*.